# Manipulate/change one dataset in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I would like to change a single record in my influxdb database. When I log in via the console, InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.3 appears.

the record looks like this:

*time savings power solar consumption
1683816226058395321 320 power 2080 -1754*

i want to change it to:

*1683816226058395321 0 power 0 0*

Can someone tell me the command?

I tried it this way which did not work:
*insert sensormeasure, solar=0, consumption=0, savings=0 1683816226058395321*